# Renci Ssh.Net downloads then errors out on file does not exist

Tags: c#, ssh.net

This code will download the requested file, but then immediately throw the error "The file path does not exist or is invalid.". I do see a newly created file in the local folder.

```
            using (var sftp = new SftpClient(FTPServer, 22, FTPUserID, FTPPwd))
            {
                sftp.Connect();
                FileSourceName = FTPServer + FTPPath + @"/spot_performance.csv";
                FileProcessName = FileProcessPath + @"\spot_performance.csv";

                using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Data\ETL\Innogames - SPOT Performance\spot_performance.csv"))
                {
                    sftp.DownloadFile(FileSourceName, fileStream);
                }
           }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also add the full complete exception message, including the stacktrace, to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was my fault. I assumed that "The file path does not exist or is invalid." was referring to the local path, not the remote path. Turns out I had an incorrect remote path. The download now completes.

My apologizes!